# Cannot set feed_previous to tf.bool in embedding_attention_seq2seq

Tags: tensorflow

I am using the `tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.embedding_attention_seq2seq()` function and I try to set the `feed_previous` argument to `tf.placeholder(tf.bool)`, however, this does not work. Error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/beamSearch/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    parser.main()
  File "D:\beamSearch\neuralParser\neuralParser.py", line 107, in main
    self.model = Model(self.args, self.textData)
  File "D:\beamSearch\neuralParser\model.py", line 26, in __init__
    self.buildNetwork()
  File "D:\beamSearch\neuralParser\model.py", line 62, in buildNetwork
    feed_previous=self.test
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\legacy_seq2seq\python\ops\seq2seq.py", line 849, in embedding_attention_seq2seq
    encoder_cell = copy.deepcopy(cell)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 297, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 218, in _deepcopy_list
    y.append(deepcopy(a, memo))
  File "C:\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 297, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 297, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 297, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 297, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 174, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects
```

Code:

```
self.dropOut = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(), name='dropOut')
self.test = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='test')

with tf.variable_scope("cell"):  # TODO: How to make this appear on the graph ?
    encoDecoCell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(self.args.hiddenSize,
                                                state_is_tuple=True)  # Or GRUCell, LSTMCell(args.hiddenSize)
    encoDecoCell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(encoDecoCell, input_keep_prob=self.dropOut,
                                                 output_keep_prob=self.dropOut)
    encoDecoCell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([encoDecoCell] * self.args.numLayers, state_is_tuple=True)

# Network input (placeholders)

with tf.name_scope('placeholder_encoder'):
    # encoderInputs are intergers, representing the index of words in the sentences
    self.encoderInputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, self.args.maxLength])

with tf.name_scope('placeholder_decoder'):
    self.decoderInputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, self.args.maxLength+2], name='decoderInputs')
    self.decoderTargets = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, self.args.maxLength+2], name='decoderTargets')
    self.decoderWeights = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, self.args.maxLength+2], name='decoderWeights')

decoderOutputs, states = tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.embedding_attention_seq2seq(
    self.encoderInputs,
    self.decoderInputs,
    encoDecoCell,
    self.textData.getInVocabularySize(),
    self.textData.getOutVocabularySize(),
    embedding_size=self.args.embeddingSize,
    feed_previous=self.test
)
```

Comment: `TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects` that is not a tensorflow error.

Comment: I also get the same error in TensorFlow 1.1.0 using the `legacy_seq2seq` package. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Actually, in the sample code, the problem is not because of feed_previous placeholder, but because of dropout placeholder (as it is inside the creation of the cell that needs to be copied). That means, if you want to use only the feed_previous, you can without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that the copy.deepcopy(cell) method does not support placeholders. Since this method is used to copy the RNN model specified as the cell parameter so that both the encoder and decoder can use the same architecture, and it does not give you any other alternatives to specify them separately, the only possibility, in case you do need to use placeholders, you may have to reproduce this seq2seq module by yourself (by copying the source code and make slight changes). In your own implementation, you just create two separate models for the encoder and decoder.